Numpy array multiplication along specific axis
I want to multiply two numpy arrays of different shapes along a specific axes without swapping them manually or adding "dummy" dimensions if possible.
For two arrays, let's say A of shape (3,2,2) and B of shape (3) i want to get the prodcut of the form
np.swapaxes(np.swapaxes(A,0,2)*B),0,2)
or alternatively
A*B[:,None,None]
However for larger arrays both methods seem to be adding noticeable calculation time to the process compared with initializing A with a shape of (2,2,3) to begin with. I can not do that though because i need A to be of the (3,2,2) shape for a later multiplication operation.
Can I avoid the double swapping of axes or the adding of "None" dimensions to improve calculation time?
EDIT:
Hi and thanks for all the answers, here is a more detailed example of what i am trying to compute exactly:
import numpy as np
from time import time

A = np.random.rand(100,100,2,20,100)
B = np.random.rand(100)
C = np.random.rand(2,20,100)
D = np.random.rand(100,100,2,20,100)

start = time()
for k in range(98,-1,-1):
    A[k,:,:,:,:] = np.pad(C[:,:,k:],((0,0),(0,0),(0,k)), 
    constant_values=1)*np.pad(B[k:],((0,k)), 
    constant_values=1)*A[k+1,:,:,:,:] + D[k,:,:,:,:]
end = time()
print('straight forward product:    ', end-start)

start = time()
for k in range(98,-1,-1):
    A[k,:,:,:,:] = np.pad(B[k:],((0,k)), constant_values=1) 
    [:,None,None,None]*A[k,:,:,:,:]*np.pad(C[:,:,k:],((0,0),(0,0), 
    (0,k)), constant_values=1)*A[k+1,:,:,:,:] + D[k,:,:,:,:]
end = time()
print('None Dummy-Dimensions:   ', end-start)

the second method takes almost twice the time for me, but I think now it is actually due to the order of the multiplication operators rather than what axis is multiplied to what axis.
edit2: I am aware that the results of those two calculations are not the same. In the first case it was just that B and C both had to be multiplied to A along the 5th axis, so order was not important and I just happened to pick this one. In the next case B needed to be multiplied to A along the 2nd axis so i changed the multiplication order, not thinking it would do anything performance wise, i suspected the lost performance comes from the B[:,None,None,None] notation.

What's wrong with A*B[:,None,None]? I'm not sure you can do anything simpler than that. You're doing an element wise multiplication, not a regular matrix multiplication.

Can you provide a code snippet with A and B properly defined ?

Nothing wrong with A*B[:,None,None] per se it just costs me time I would like to save in the calculation

Can just take np.ones((3,2,2)) for A and np.ones((3)) for B I guess

For what sizes do you see an increase in time?  B[:,None,None] makes a view, which by usual experience takes negligible time.  But putting a very large dimension first versus last may make a difference in time due to memory caching/paging issues.

In practice my A‘s shape is ballpark (2,20,100,100,100) and B of (100) the multiplication operation also had to run many times like 100 to 1000 times
B needs to be multiplied to third axis in my case.

In my quick tests, multiplying along the third axis is actually faster than along the last.
In [135]: A=np.ones((2,2,100,100,100)); B=np.ones((100))

In [136]: timeit A*B
17.9 ms ± 333 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [137]: timeit A*B[:,None,None]
16 ms ± 1.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

einsum
The other answer suggested einsum.  I'm not seeing any improvement
In [138]: timeit np.einsum('ijklm,k->ijklm',A,B)
22.7 ms ± 576 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [139]: timeit np.einsum('ijklm,m->ijklm',A,B)
22.8 ms ± 2.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


Thank you for testing this. I am somehow confused why there is no difference in calculation time. I will test it again when I am back at work tomorrow to see if I missed something else.

Regarding the einsum I commented above that I suspect it to be a different operation, a tensor contraction. Would that make sense with it taking more time in your test, ig it would because of the implicit sum operation.

While einsum often is used for a contraction, with this indexing it doesn't sum-of-products anything.  Look at print(np.einsum_path('ijklm,m->ijklm',A,B)[1]).  Same ijklm 5d on both the lhs and rhs.

@hpaulj maybe you can get a slightly improved speed if you change the array to fortran / column layout, when doing A*B.

@Mercury. That's exactly what the first test is verifying

you can try using the einsum numpy library function which is quite faster,
import numpy as np
A, B = np.random.rand(3, 2, 2), np.random.rand(3)

%%timeit
np.einsum('ijk,i->ijk', A, B)
>>> 1.19 µs ± 22.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)


At first glance looking up the einsum function I am not sure this is the same thing as the multiplication I mentioned. Aren’t the shapes different afterward because of the summation? I expect the return of your example to be of shape (2,2) instead of (3,2,2), is that not correct?

@Sebastian you are mistaking it for "ijk,i->jk". But it is "ijk,i->ijk". It will remain (3, 2, 2).
